# counting fraction

Tags: python-2.7

my problem is with numpy arrays and fraction counting

Comment: If you give some input-output, it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Can't you post a little example? Maybe an input with just 5 string and the desired output.

Comment: what does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Yes I see the problem now, I will see it, don't give up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you make:

```
str(data[:,i:i+1])
```

numpy.array `__str__` method returns the desired output if the length of the array is <= 1000

But when the length is > 1000 it returns something like this:

```
[['E']
['E']
['E']
..., 
['E']
['E']
['E']]
```

So there is the error! Try to modify your method so you count the matches not from the string. I will try to find out too.

**Edit**

Converting the `numpy.array` to a list, using its `tolist()` method is the solution:

```
list = []
for i in range(len(wtseq)):
    a = float(str(data[:,i:i+1].tolist()).count(wtseq[i])) / len(datainput)
    list.append(a)
print list
```